# Dependency on capacitance

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

We know that when capacitance of a capacitor changes,it means the distance between the plates changes and as potential difference of the capacitor is dependent on the capacitor, i.e ($V=Ed$), the potential difference changes as well. Does that mean we can conclude the reciprocal? If potential difference changes, then capacitance will change too? If not, what is the reason?

Comment: If it is held at a fixed voltage the potential different does not change. You need to specify the conditions of the problem better. It is held at a fixed voltage or not?

Comment: (e.g., is it in a circuit with a battery? Or just two charged plates floating out in space?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We know that when capacitance of a capacitor changes, it means the
> distance between the plates changes...

Not necessarily. The capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor based on its physical characteristics is give by

$$C=\frac{\epsilon A}{d}$$

Where $d$ is the plate separation, $A$ the area of each plate, and $\epsilon$ is the permittivity of the space between the plates.  $\epsilon$ is often given as $\epsilon=\epsilon_{r}\epsilon_0$  where $\epsilon_{r}$ is the relative permittivity or dielectric constant and $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space (or air). So the capacitance can change with a different dielectric and the same plate separation.

> ...and as potential difference of the capacitor is dependent on the
> capacitor, i.e ($V=Ed$)

The potential difference depends on the capacitance and the net charge $Q$ on each plate according to

$$C=\frac{Q}{V}$$

The electric field between the parallel plates (ignoring edge effects) is given by

$$E=\frac{V}{d}$$

> If potential difference changes, then capacitance will change too? If
> not, what is the reason?

Again, not necessarily, because $C=\frac{Q}{V}$. A change in potential for the same physical capacitor results in change in the net charge $Q$ by the same factor.

Consider a capacitor that is fully charged with potential difference of $V$ but not connected to a voltage source (e.g., a battery). We now connect it to a battery (in series with a resistor so as not to damage the capacitor) of voltage $2V$. The charge on the capacitor will increase to $2Q$. So the voltage across the capacitor plates is now $2V$ but the charge per volt, which is the electrical definition of capacitance, will be the same, i.e., $\frac{Q}{V}$.

Hope this helps.